# Sould SASS be installed as a 'dependency' or as a 'devDependency?

Tags: npm, sass, dependencies

Should sass be installed as a 'dependency' or as a 'devDependency'?

In the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass#usage) says: " You can also add it to your project using npm install --save-dev sass."

But in the [Install Sass page](https://sass-lang.com/install) there is no information about this topic.

I have it like this and it works:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "parcel": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.8"
}
```

But I wonder whether I should better have it as a devDependency.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093609/12686390

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly advise against installing npm packages like `sass` as a global dependency, this is particular important when you work collaboratively with others. The packages required for a project to run out of the box should be installed within the package itself. This ensures everything is contained within, and the project is capable of running standalone by a participant cloning the repo and running `npm i`.

As you mentioned, the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) for `sass` recommends installing it to a project via running `npm install --save-dev sass`. It should be noted that `sass` is a preprocessor which compiles `.sass` and .`scss` files to `.css`. It is therefore not required to run at production because when we compile our production build (such as with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)), the associated `.css` files would have been generated. Thus, it is safe to download it as a dev dependency because we only need it during development.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it depends of your necessity and choice.

If you use the command `npm install -g sass` displayed in Sass's documentation, it will install sass globally in your machine and the sass package will not be added in your dependencies:

```
npm install -g sass
```

Although, if you run `--save-dev` it will be in your dependencies and always that someone clone your project and run `npm install`, the sass package will be installed (together with all the other dependencies).

Also I believe you can mix these commands and install globally and in your dependencies if you want: `npm install -g --save-dev sass`.

There are similar questions that can also help you:

[What is the difference between --save and --save-dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891211/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-save-dev)